# Gnome Shortcut for rollup / unroll window

Tags: centos, gnome, x-windows

is there a keyboard shortcut that can be set to roll up a window in CetnOs using Gnome desktop? I am running CentOS release version 6.5 and Gnome desktop version 2.28.2.  I have the mouse setup to roll the window up so that only the title bar is showing when double clicking it, it will unroll the window when double clicking it again. I am wondering if there is a way to set a keyboard shortcut to get this same functionality such that I can alt-tab to different windows and then roll them using the keyboard shortcut instead of having to use the mouse. Currently when you alt-tab to a window it automatically unrolls it which is fine, but then I would like a keyboard shortcut to roll it back up instead of having to double click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts for "Toggle Shaded State". There you can set a key to toggle the shaded state of a window.
[image: This is from MATE, but it should be the same in GNOME 2.28.2]

Comment: Thanks this worked. I didn't know what window shading meant...